# Prove $x\text{cos} (1/x)$ is a regulated function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $g(x)=xcos(1/x)$ for $x \in (0,1]$ and $g(0)=0$.

I'd like to prove that $g(x)$ is regulated.

The definition of a regulated function is :

[image]

I'm trying to go with the "alternative" definition:

$||g(x)- \phi||_{\infty} \lt \epsilon$ $\Rightarrow$ $||xcos(1/x) - \phi||_{\infty} \lt \epsilon$

So, if I set $||\phi||_{\infty} = \epsilon - ||xcos(1/x)||_{\infty}-1$ then

$||xcos(1/x) - \phi||_{\infty} \leq ||xcos(1/x)||_{\infty} + \epsilon - ||xcos(1/x)||_{\infty}-1 \lt \epsilon$

Hence $||g(x) - \phi||_{\infty} \lt \epsilon$

I think this is not correct. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Let $P=\{p_0,...,p_k\}$ be a parition of $[0,1]$ such that $p_i-p_{i-1} \lt \delta$ for all $i=1,...,k$

Let $\psi \in S[0,1]$ defined by $$\psi(x)=p_{i-1}cos(\frac{1}{p_{i-1}})\text{ if $x \in [p_{i-1},p_i)$ and $\psi(1)=f(1)$}$$

We have: $$|xcos(1/x)-\psi(x)|=|xcos(1/x)-p_{i-1}cos(1/x)| \lt \epsilon$$

Since $$|x-p_{i-1}|\lt \delta$$ so that $$||xcos(1/x)-\psi||_{\infty} \lt \epsilon$$

Hence $xcos(1/x)$ is regulated.

Comment: You need to produce a function $\phi$ that satisfies the condition, or show that non-existence is absurd.

Comment: @saulspatz but i did produce a function $\phi$ where $||\phi||_{\infty} = \epsilon - ||xcos(1/x)||_{\infty}-1$. Isn't that fine?

Comment: You actually did not produce a function. You seem to have given more of a convoluted condition for such a function. As evidence I can ask what would your function be roughly when $\epsilon=1/2$.

Comment: As a hint I would suggest using the fact that $f$ is uniformly continuous, and define $\phi$ piecewise using that property.

Comment: No, you didn't define $\phi$.  You just gave a condition on $||\phi||_{\infty}$ without saying what $\phi$ itself is.

Comment: Are you still struggling with this and want an answer?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur could you check if my edit is correct?

Comment: You are lacking an argument as to why such a $\delta$ exists. I also don't know what $f$ is. But aside from that I think that the argument is right.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur could you write a proof as in how you would do it?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $g(x)$ is continuous in $[0,1]$ it is uniformly continuous there and there exists $\delta_\epsilon>0$ such that if $x,y\in [0,1]$ and $\vert x-y\vert<\delta_\epsilon$ , then $\vert g(x)-g(y)\vert<\epsilon$.

As you said, for a partition $P=\{ p_i \}_{i=0}^n$ satisfying $\vert p_i-p_{i-1}\vert<\delta_\epsilon$, we define

$$ \phi(x)=g(p_{i-1}) \quad \text{for }\quad  x\in\big[p_{i-1},p_i\big), \quad \text{and} \quad  \phi(1)=g(1)$$

If $x\in [p_{i-1},p_i)$ then $\vert x-p_{i-1}\vert<\delta_\epsilon$ and

$$ \vert g(x)-\phi(x) \vert=\vert g(x)-g(p_{i-1})\vert< \epsilon. $$

And since $g(x)=\phi(x)$, you get in general that $\Vert g-\phi\Vert_\infty<\epsilon$ while $\phi$ is a step function.

This how I would write it. As an aside, I think this argument shows that any continuous function is regulated on a compact interval.